# change every nonzero value to 1

Tags: functions

I need a function that does this:
$$ f(x)=
\begin{cases}    
      0, & \text{if}\ x=0 \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $$
However I want it to be able to be put into a graphic calculator, so I'd like a solution without ceiling or floor or anything that wouldn't work (I also want to do some algebra with it later but with ceil and floor it becomes hard to do). I already thought of $min(1,n^2)$ but this won't work for $0<x<1$. It would be finished if I add a ceil() to that, but unfortunately I can't do that, and I can't think of any other way.

I hope I've been clear on the ceil/floor thing, feel free to ask.

Is there some kind of formula for this?

Comment: What discontinuous functions are you allowing?

Comment: I don't get why you keep speaking about ceiling and floor -- the definition you have already mentions neither of these. Is your real question how to input a definition-by-cases into your graphic calculator? If so, you'll probably need to reveal its make and model ...

Comment: $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|x|}$

Comment: Or, in the spirit of @Hagen's proposal, $1-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\int_0^n \cos(xt)\,dt $.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am seeking for a single function that isn't made up from multiple cases. Sorry if that was not made clear.

Comment: @ThePJ: **Why** do you want that? If your calculator is not excessively antique, it _will_ have a syntax for inputting your straightforward definition by cases; it's just a matter of figuring out what it is. (Your function is a single funciton no matter how you choose to express its definition).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Nice, but as far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to put a limit in my calculator.

Comment: How about $1-0^{x^2}$, then?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point

Comment: @HenningMakholm That should work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Henning Makholm in [his post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944073/change-every-nonzero-value-to-1#comment3991257_1944073)
$$1-0^{x^2}$$
This function becomes 0 with x=0 and 1 with other values.

$1-0^{(\pm6)^2}=1-0^{36}=1-0=1$

$1-0^{0^2}=1-0^0=1-1=0$

Answer (score 1):

It is a calculator, so you can exploit that it will make approximations.

Something like
$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+10^{-99}}$$
might work for not-too-small values of $x$.

The number $10^{-99}$ is just the smallest positive number that can be handled by a standard calculator. Change this if your machine is different.

Comment: It works, but I wouldn't call it beautiful

Comment: It didn't mean to be. Feel free to add to it some colourful flowers.